# Python: retrieve substring bounded by indentations on a text file

Tags: python, text-files

I am having trouble on how to even identify indentations on a text file with Python (the ones that appear when you press tab). I thought that using the split function would be helpful, but it seems like there has to be a physical character that can act as the 'separator'.

Here is a sample of the text, where I am trying to retrieve the string 'John'. Assume that the spaces are the indentations:

```
15:50:00    John    1029384
```

All help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: *I thought that using the split function would be helpful* - it is... Did you try it? [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with the default argument splits all whitespaces, including tabs... *"If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive __whitespace__ are regarded as a single separator"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tabs are represented by `\t`. See https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp for a longer list.

So we can do the following:

```
s = "15:50:00   John    1029384"
s.split("\t") # Output: ['15:50:00', 'John', '1029384']
```

If you know regex, then you can use look-ahead and look-behind as follows:

```
import re
re.search("(?<=\t).*?(?=\t)", s)[0] # Output: "John"
```

Obviously both methods will need to be made more robust by considering edge cases and error handling (eg., what happens if there are fewer -- or more -- than two tabs in the string -- how do you identify the name in that case?)

Answer (score 2):

Dependent on the program that you used for creating the file, what is actually inserted when you press <kbd>TAB</kbd> may either be a TAB character (`\t`) or a series of spaces.

You were actually right in thinking that `split()` is a way to do what you want. If you don't pass any arguments to it, it treats both series of whitespace and tabs as a single separator:

```
s = "15:50:00   John    1029384"
t = "15:50:00\tJohn\t1029384"

s.split() # Output: ['15:50:00', 'John', '1029384']
t.split() # Output: ['15:50:00', 'John', '1029384']
```